# explanation of this function that returns diag() in R

Tags: r

why this? `y <- min(dim(x))`?

I tried this code without this `c <- vector()` and got 25 (`c <- x[i,i]` was in the loop. Using `c[i]` in the loop gave me an error).

```
x <- matrix(1:25, 5,5)
> diag(x)
> n <- function(x){
     y <- min(dim(x))
     c <- vector()
     for(i in 1:y){
       c[i] <- x[i,i]
     }
   c
}
> n(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `y <- min(dim(x))` is used to determine the smaller dimension of the matrix. So, using `y`, the number of iterations of the `for` loop is fixed to be equal to this dimension of the matrix. Then, `[i,i]` is used to access the diagonal elements.

In your example, the matrix size is `5x5`, so both dimensions are equal. So, for `y` being 5, you loop with `i` from 1 till 5. Now, since you're using `[i,i]` for the matrix indexes, you get [2,2] after [1,1]. Essentially, the `[i,i]` selects the elements when both the row number and the column number are the same value.

If you remove the `c <- vector()`, `c` is treated as a single variable, and hence `c[i]` throws an error. Also note that the value of `c` keeps getting overwritten and hence, on exiting the loop, you get the last value, which is 25 in this case.

Comment: This what I visualize from your answer, the min dimension is first [1,1], then [2,2],[3,3],[4,4] and [5,5]. why is the the next smaller one after [1,1] not [1,2]?

Comment: @zizu check the updated answer. I think it'll be helpful if you look into how matrices work, in general, and [in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html)

Comment: If i in seq_along(x)  is  specified and  x[ i, i ] picks the diagonal elements of the matrix, shouldn't c [ i ] <-x[ i, i ] produce the diagonal ? i get this: Error in x[ i, i ] : subscript out of bounds - is this because the length 25 doesn't match the length of the diaognals 5?

Comment: yes. `x` has 25 elements, so `seq_along(x)` goes beyond 5, and then `x[i,i]` fails. Also, it's always better to submit a fresh question for follow-up rather than posting it in the comments. :)